# How to install PyDev Extensions

Tags: eclipse-plugin, aptana, pydev

After installing PyDev in Eclipse, and seeking to know its features, I noticed that in Windows> Preferences> PyDev, I have not found a guide for PyDev Extensions

How I can I include it in my PyDev?

- My Eclipse SDK version 4.2.2
- Build id: M20130204-1200 My version is
- PyDev 2.7.0.2013012902 Aptana Studio 3 version is
  3.3.2.201302081500-7G7F17UIS_IYK7UrNh8biKtz0dax

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Python and PyDev, googled a bit and found in http://marketplace.eclipse.org/user/879/favorites, that the extensions were incorporated into the product. I apologize to anyone who has spent his time in reading this my improper question.